# Spark Graphx deadlock when execute my program in mutilple process

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

When I push my undergraduate design. I have encountered a strange problem，when I execute my program in single process, the program can finish it normally. But when I change it to multiple process mode, the program suspend and not recover from suspend state. I find some log in run terminal log, like is :

```
23/04/23 10:29:07 INFO Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 2:
[rdd_2_0]
23/04/23 10:29:07 INFO Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 3:
```

My code is as follows：

```
def sample_process_test2(file_path: String): Unit = {
  Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARNING)
  Logger.getLogger("org.eclipse.jetty.server").setLevel(Level.OFF)
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleGraphX")
    .setMaster("local[4]")
  val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
  val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc,
    file_path).partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.RandomVertexCut)
  val canonicalGraph = graph.removeSelfEdges().convertToCanonicalEdges()
  val sortDegreeEdges = optimize.sort_edges_with_degree(canonicalGraph, sc)
  val totalEdgeCount = sortDegreeEdges.length
  val degreeLocationDict = optimize.gen_degree_location_Dictionary(canonicalGraph, sortDegreeEdges)
  val sortDegreeDict = mutable.LinkedHashMap(degreeLocationDict.toSeq.sortBy(_._1): _*)
  def collect_edge(proportion: Double,
                   sortDegreeDict: mutable.LinkedHashMap[Int, (Int, Int)]): (Int, Int) = {
    var cnt = 0
    for ((key, value) <- sortDegreeDict) {
      cnt = cnt + (value._2 - value._1)
      if (cnt * 1.0 / totalEdgeCount > proportion)
        return (key, cnt)
    }
    (-1, cnt)
  }
  val degreeMap = canonicalGraph.degrees.collect().toMap
  var subGraphMap = new mutable.HashMap[Int, Graph[Int, Int]]()

  val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()

  val (targetDegree, endIdx) = collect_edge(0.45, sortDegreeDict)
  (1 to targetDegree).par.map(it => {
    val subGraph = canonicalGraph.subgraph(vpred = (id, attr) => degreeMap.get(id).get < it)
    subGraphMap.put(it, subGraph)
    Unit
  })
  val subGraphMapBroadcast = sc.broadcast(subGraphMap)

  def par_compute(iterator: Iterator[Int]): Iterator[(Int, Int)] = {
    iterator.toArray.par.map(it => {
      val subGraph = subGraphMapBroadcast.value.get(it).get
      val triangleCount = subGraph.triangleCount().vertices.map(_._2).reduce(_ + _) / 3
      println(it,triangleCount)
      (it, triangleCount)
    }).toIterator
  }
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to targetDegree, 4)
  val rdd_result = rdd.mapPartitions(par_compute).collect().foreach(println)
  val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
  println(end - begin)
}
```

here is my spark task web ui. It seems like the jobs don't release the cpu.

[image]

Can someone help me see why this task cannot be continued?